# How can I display the result of a view in a parent view?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m using @Ajax.ActionLink() to render partial view.  The result of the submitted form in the view is displayed in another form with a message your mail has been sent.  I know I may be able to do this with a popup but I plan to do other stuff on the resulting view later.

I’ve used this method in the past...

```
   @Html.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id =myId })
```

but this requires having the parent page call the partial view.  Since I called the partial view with the ajaxlink, what I want is after the action does its thing, instead of the view going to a new page with this…

```
 return View();
```

…just put the content of the returned view in the parent view so that navigation away from the current view does not happen.

How can I display the result of a view in a parent view?

Thanks for any info on this.

Comment: You can use `ajax` with JS, better if jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call a jquery method on your parent view.in your your jquery method, show a message that "your mail has been sent" and then redirect to another view from that jquery method.your problem will be solved